# React JS - State not returning to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem here in react js, the problem is the state is not returning to false. What happen is when I clicked a button the state becomes true, but when I clicked it again it doesn't return to false although it meets the requirement for the condition.

Here is my code:

```
  const [isTest, setIsTest] = useState(false)

  const testFunction = () => {
      if (from_first_box) {
        if (first_box_id !== 0) {
          setIsTest(true)
        }
      }
      else if (from_second_box) {
        if (second_box_id !== 0) {
          setIsTest(false)
        }
      }

    }
```

Expected result is when the `first_box_id !== 0` the isTest state should be true and when the `second_box_id !==0` the isTest state should be false, Thanks for helping

Comment: typo? `setIsTestTo()` => `setIsTest()`

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You should use setIsTest instead of setIsTestTo.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this:

```
  const [isTest, setIsTest] = useState(false)

  const testFunction = () => {
        if (from_first_box && first_box_id) {
          setIsTest(true)
        }
        else if (from_second_box && second_box_id ) {
          setIsTest(false)
        }

  }
```